# Enable SSL on every page Prestashop

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying enable SSL on every page in my web shop based on Prestashop 1.6.1.7. I turn on options in BO ("enable SSL" and "enable SSL protocol on every page") and now I cant access to my webshop by http:// protocol (I see white page), only https:// working.

I was trying force redirect in .htaccess but with no effect, it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

or

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.your_site.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I disabled "enable SSL protocol on every page" option and now I can access to webshop by http://. 
Additionally https:// works properly on order process and login/register page. But I would like https:// on every page.

I have enabled debug mode and there is no errors.

Comment: Hello mate , i cant get clearly . A question , when u enabled SSL it means you need https then why you try to access http which is non SSL ???

Comment: Oh I forgot add that I see white page when I try to access http:// . It should redirect from http:// to https://

Answer (score 5):

For me it was works solution for version  1.7.2.0 to add redirect from http to https

(1) Go to **/classes/controller/FrontController.php**

and set SSL connection flag to TRUE, right below

public $ssl = false; **change to** public $ssl = true;

(2) Then go to **database** and find **PS_SSL_ENABLED** parameter in __configuration table and change it value from "0" to "**1**"

Comment: You will also be required to change PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE in the same database table to "1"

Answer (score 1):

To do not see "white page", enable Developer mode as described here: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/PrestaShop's+developer+tools

and change your question with the error that you see.

Comment: As I said on my question: "I have enabled debug mode and there is no errors."

Comment: and caching disabled and so on?

Comment: Yes, cache and other are disebled

Comment: what do you use in *curl -I site.com* or chrome dev tools, is redirect happening correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To enable HTTPS in all pages of your Prestashop website follow this

> 1. Find your .htaccess file (usually in the root folder)
> 2. open the file ---- >Find for "RewriteEngine on" if its off make it on
> 3. Under that write this below code

```
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$https://yoursitename.com/$1 [R,L]
```

> 4. Save and upload the file to respective directory

**NOTE:** Extra rewriteRule may be present under "RewriteEngine on" Ignore do not modify until you understand it fully.

Hope this helps mate !

Comment: Problem is that as I said before, changes in .htaccess not working. Even yours. But when I delete htaccess, rewrite doesnt work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache server, you can try the following code in your .htaccess file to fix the issue.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: .htaccess not responding to any entries :/

Answer (score 0):

Log in as Administrator in Prestashop at Domains
Enable SSL and SSL on all pages options under Configure > Shop Parameters > General

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hviCK.png)